# Login using LoginManager class

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am developing an Android App. In my App I need to use facebook login. Everything set's up as per facebook recommendation. I try to find tutorial but all tutorials just talk about how to do this using given inbuilt Button by `facebook sdk`. So I need process of doing that using any Android Widget like ImageView, Buttons etc. I learn somehow that it can be done using `LoginManager` class. But I don't how to do it. So anybody please help me out with this.

Comment: @MD why you can't help me dude.

Comment: I am just kidding. ya why not? off course help you. wait a min

Comment: First you tell me what is `LoginManager`?

Comment: @MD dude it's a class which I guess can be used for facebook login and other facebook sdk functions. I don't explored it till now, So I don't much about it.

Comment: If you dont know about that then why don't you search on _Google_.

Comment: @MD I try to do but can't find appropriate example. Dude please help me I know you can. I am just beginner and you are really super experienced guy. So sir please help.

Comment: Post your attempt at using the LoginManager class and ask a question about where you're getting stuck.